# Is there a way to clear the "info" editor?

Tags: interface

Say there was a mistake in a script, it didn't compile. In an info area that's bigger then just a small strip, there will be one or more red error messages.

How to get rid of them with a keypress?

Comment: I don't think you can other then reopening your file.

Answer (score 7):

OK, I discovered the solution, press <kbd>A</kbd> twice to select all and then <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd> to get rid of these lines.