# Clearing info with python script

Tags: scripting

I am planning to log operator usage in blender. For that I found this operator - bpy.ops.ui.reports_to_textblock() collects all the info data into a text block.

I need to clear the info screen every time after collecting the data.
Pressing A & then X , helps clear the screen , but how can I do it with python script ?

Also I want to do it once every 5 mins. Is there a way to setup time recurring tasks in blender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using the bpy.ops.info operators**

Here is a quick little test script.  The info area operators' context are overriden to emulate running in the info area.

- Assumes the info area is `screen.areas[0]`
- Assumes no prior selection of reports.

Script:

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
info = context.screen.areas[0] # do properly
c = context.copy()
c["area"] = info

# test call
bpy.ops.info.select_all_toggle(c)
bpy.ops.info.report_delete(c)
```

Script version of [Is there a way to clear the "info" editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18609/is-there-a-way-to-clear-the-info-editor).  Might need to run all or some twice to make sure all is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
from os import system, name   
import datetime

#clear function 
def clear(): 

    # for windows 
    if name == 'nt': 
        system('cls') 
    # for mac and linux(here, os.name is 'posix') 
    else: 
        system('clear') 

clear()
last_clear = datetime.datetime.now().minute

if abs(datetime.datetime.now().minute - last_clear) >= 5:
    clear()
    last_clear = datetime.datetime.now().minute

print now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second
```

Comment: the clear() function is clearing my terminal. I'd rather want to clear the logs in "bpy.context.area.type = 'INFO'". Generally we hover the mouse on info screen , press A to select all the logs and click X/Del button to clear it.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question if you do not find a more elegant solution you could just press keys from python script like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136734/key-presses-in-python